# IP changing script not working from cron ? Python

Tags: python, subprocess, cron

**I have made this script to change ip of eth0 interface.It is working fine from the console but not working from the cron.Even there is no error coming on cron for the script.Please guide me through this**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import os
ip=['192.168.X.X','192.168.X.X','192.168.X.X']
gateway='192.168.X.1'
netmask='225.225.225.0'


currentip=os.popen("ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'").read()
currentip=currentip.strip()
print currentip
lip=len(ip)

for item in ip:
    index=ip.index(item)
    if item==currentip:

        if index==lip-1:        
            index=0
            newip=ip[index]
            subprocess.call(['ifconfig','eth0',newip,'netmask',netmask,'up'])
            subprocess.call(['route','add','default','gw',gateway])
        else:
            index=index+1
            newip=ip[index]
            print newip
            subprocess.call(['ifconfig','eth0',newip,'netmask',netmask,'up'])
            subprocess.call(['route','add','default','gw',gateway])
```

Cron code is

```
06 12 * * * cd /root/system/; python ip.py
```

Comment: I will put aside my distaste at seeing grep, cut, and awk called from python.  The most common reason for jobs not working in cron is that the environments are different.  If there is anything in a startup file, like `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, which your program relies on, then it won't be there.  `$PATH`, for example, and the current directory.  Better to give cron a full path name for the python program.

Comment: and use full paths inside the script for ifconfig, grep ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an 'absolute path' problem to me.
please use absolute path for File, and Python Compiler

`06 12 * * * /usr/bin/python /root/system/ip.py`